# Teradata Install 32bit appears to have failed

Tags: installation, odbc, teradata

I'm getting the error "The installation of ODBC -32bit appears to have failed. Do you want to continue the installation?" and I'm not sure how to solve it.

I've never installed teradata before, and I've tried clicking yes to continue. Even if I continue I'm not able to find teradata in my list of drivers when I'm creating a new data source.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I'm installing the 16.10.05.00 version that I got from the teradata website into a Windows 10 laptop.

I have had other co-workers be able to install the version on similar laptops just fine.

Comment: What version are you installing? From where? Onto what operating system version?

Comment: You seem to have two accounts.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts about how to merge them.